# Russell's paradox: intuition behind schema of separation versus comprehension

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand some ideas behind the ZFC axioms and I am following a book by Thomas Jech (Set Theory, 3rd edition, 2000). Unfortunately he is rather "to the point" and does not dwell too much on expanding on any intuitive ideas behind the axioms. In particular I am eager to understand some of the intuition behind Russell's paradox and why this should lead to the schema of comprehension being dropped in favour of the schema of separation;

**Axiom Schema of Separation**: If $P$ is a property with parameter $p$ then for any $X$ and $p$ there exists a set $Y=\{u\in X:P(u,p)\}$ that contains all those $u\in X$ that have property $P$

**Schema of comprehension**: If $P$ is a property then there exists a set $Y=\{x:P(x)\}$

After reading page 4 from Jech he writes about Russell's paradox showing that the set $S=\{X:X\not\in X\}$ cannot exist (or maybe should not exist in an axiomatic framework). This can be seen to use the property $P(X)=1\Longleftrightarrow X\not\in X$. I must admit *I view this as a class* since the elements of $S$ are sets, but adapted the property to be elements $P(x)=1\Longleftrightarrow x\not\in x$ and think the contradiction is still valid. Jech shortly after introduces classes, and whilst I am happy about the difference (in ZFC classes do not exist but are used for convenience), I am confused about this issue in its use here in Russell's paradox.

**Using the schema of separation**

For any set $X$ the set $Y_{1}=\{u\in X:P(u)\}$ exists and is the set of elements that do not belong to themselves. Given for any element $x$ we clearly have $x\in x$ since $x=x$ then $Y_{1}=\emptyset$ follows. More formally: suppose an element $u$ exists such that $u\in Y_{1}$. Then this implies $u\in X$ satisfies $P(x)=1$ and hence $u\not\in u$. But since all $x\in X$ satisfy $x=x$ and hence $x\in x$ we conclude $u\not\in X$, which contradicts $u\in Y_{1}$. Hence $u\not\in Y_{1}$, which implies $Y_{1}=\emptyset$. Conversely assuming $u\not\in Y_{1}$ just means no element $x\in X$ satisfies $x\not\in x$, which we already know, so no contradiction is obtained.

**Intuition**: although the property $P$ is rather silly since it is self-evident no element of a *set* $X$ can satisfy it, drawing elements *from* $X$ and keeping only those elements satisfying $P$ must lead to one coming away empty handed, or possessing nothing - but nothing is still something, and using separation in combination with this property confirms this intuition by stating only the set containing nothing satisfies $P$.

**Using the schema of comprehension**

The set $Y_{2}=\{u:P(u)\}$ exists where $Y_{2}\not=\emptyset$ is a possibility that is *not* ruled out, the reason being $u$ simply "appears from nowhere" rather than being drawn from a set (from which we can come away empty handed). But if $u\in Y_{2}$, then since $u=u$ implies $u\in u$ then $P(u)=0$ must be true and hence $u\not\in Y_{2}$ follows which is a contradiction. Conversely if $u\not\in Y_{2}$ then $P(y)=0$ meaning $u\not\in u$ which is a contradiction of $u=u$. Either way $Y_{2}\not=\emptyset$ cannot exist as a set, and the schema of comprehension must be dropped in favour of the schema of separation.

Comment: I don't fully understand what's going on in the "Using the schema of separation" paragraph. In ZF, the set $\{u \in X : u \notin u\}$ is always equal to $X$, because ZF proves that for any set $x$, we have $x \notin x$. In particular $x = x$ does not imply that $x \in x$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks for your reply. Perhaps this is to do with me using $x$ as an element rather than a set? Surely for $x=2.3$ say, and viewing $x$ as the singleton set $\{2.3\}$ we have $2.3\in\{2.3\}$? To me intuitively $x\in x$ means $x\in\{x\}$ which is true? Is this not correct? I can (I think) see how $X\not\in X$ for a set $X$.

Comment: No. $x\in x$ and $x\in\{x\}$ are two different statements.

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin for your reply. Please forgive me but what is wrong with claiming $x\in x$ if $x$ is an element (i.e. not a set)? Can we not switch between viewing $x$ (the element) and $\{x\}$ the set? Presumably $x\in \{x\}$ is OK to say but $x\in x$ is not?

Comment: You can only state $x\in y$ when $x$ is an element of $y$. There is no distinction between being an "element" and being a set. No, you cannot "switch" between $x$ and $\{x\}$, as they are fundamentally distinct things. For example, $\varnothing$ has no elements, but $\{\varnothing\}$ has an element. Are you under the impression that one can switch between thinking you have an empty bag and thinking you have a bag that has an empty bag inside it? You cannot.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ahh yes clearly I am under this impression, +1 for that great empty bag example: so $x\in\{x\}$ is true (I have a bag containing $x$ and so $x$ is in the bag), but $x\in x$ is false since $x\not=\{x\}$ (i.e $x$ is not a bag containing $x$)? I was too lazy by arguing we can "view" or "think" of $x$ as $\{x\}$. Now Izaak's comment makes sense to me. So I need to amend my arguments in the question, but is the intuition correct: schema of separation permits $\emptyset$ to exist as a set and thus no paradox arises?

Comment: $x\in x$ may be true or false depending on what $x$ is. In Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory it is always false, **not** because $x\neq\{x\}$, but because the Axiom of Regularity forbids it. There are other set theories where $x\in x$ may be true for **some** (but never all) sets.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks again, your comments are very enlightening - for instance your comment about the axioms not distinguishing between sets and elements I had not really appreciated, for the very reason I learnt set theory "the quick way" where classes have sets as elements and sets have elements. I am paying the price for that now! This does not come through obviously in the Jech book, hence these comments are so valuable to me.

Comment: I'm glad that you're happier with your understanding now! I will say that Jech's book is fairly advanced. I think trying to learn the basics of axiomatic set theory from it is probably a bit over-ambitious. He does briefly cover the prerequisites but I think it will be hard to follow if you've had no exposure to advanced axiomatic set theory before. He will certainly take ideas like "in set theory, elements of sets are themselves sets" for granted. You may benefit from at least having a look at some more friendly/introductory texts!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I am finding this out about Jech! Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: I first learned axiomatic set theory from an undergrad course. There are notes from this course [here](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/ii/Logic_and_Set_Theory.pdf), and some recommended books. The ones by Forster and Johnstone are based on the very same course! I haven't worked through either and there will be differences between all three texts (the authors all disagree on what's the best way to structure a logic & set theory course). I'll say that you shouldn't neglect the "logic" part - to really understand ZFC it's essential to have some understanding of first-order logic.

Comment: Thanks for the course notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! Many paradoxes exploit self-reference to be formulated. A classic example is the liar's paradox: how do we assign a truth value to the sentence "This sentence is not true"? By referring to itself, we get this circular problem by which the sentence must be false if it is true, but true if it is false. Russel's paradox deals with a particular type of self-reference called being "impredicative." A definition for a new set $X$ is called impredicative if the definition ranges over a class of sets that *already* contains $X$. The Russell set $S=\{X|X\not\in X\}$ that you mention relies on this feature: the condition $X\not\in X$ ranges over *all possible* sets, which includes the set $S$ that we're trying to define. This is how we invoke the paradox, by asking if $S\in S$: if so, the condition for entry $X\not\in X$ shows that it is not; if not, the condition for entry show that it is.

Thus, full comprehension gives rise to self-reference in the form of sets that can have impredicative definitions. Separation fixes this by only letting the defining formula for a set range over sets contained in a set that *already exists* as opposed to all sets in an unrestricted way. Along with other $ZF$ axioms like the axiom of foundation, we can imagine sets to be constructed in stages, where new sets are only constructed with reference to already constructed sets, excluding the possibility of defining a set impredicatively by reference to itself. (The formal way to see this is via the von Neumann hierarchy of sets.)

Comment: Thank you for this confirmation, and for fleshing out my intuition with some precise terms such as "impredicative" on which to learn some more about.